# SQL Query to Update one column based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, conditional-statements

For Example table 'tbl' has a,b,dt and flag columns. Where a and b columns together forms unique combination.

Need to update all flag column as inactive for all records with future date

and mark flag as active for the same records with the max(dt)<=current date.

Comment: what do you mean by "MAX(DT)"? Do you have multiple date columns in a single row, and want to check if any of those have a value less than the current date? Can you please post some sample data, expected results, and your attempt(s) please?

Comment: 'dt' Column consists of date, based on which the flag needs to be updated, If for one unique combination the date is future date flag shoulb be inactive and for the same combination the next record with proper date should be active

Comment: Something like `update tbl set flag = 0 where dt > GETDATE()`?  If a and b form unique values, there shouldn’t be same records.

Answer (score 0):

As Nikolaus said:

> try this and it should work  :

```
UPDATE tbl SET FLAG = 0 WHERE dt > GETDATE();
UPDATE tbl SET FLAG = 1 WHERE dt <= GETDATE();
```

Comment: This is the same as : UPDATE tbl SET FLAG = case when dt > GETDATE() then 0 else 1 end

Comment: Thank you @andesta.erfan